# Else condition never reached in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I have a populateResult function that populates the field ResultAccount. If df3.AccounName2 is empty, then df3["ResultAccount"] is df3.AccountName. Else df3["ResultAccount"] is df3.AccountName2.

In my code, that elif condition is never reached. Only the if condition gets evaluated and it populates the ResultAccount. Not sure why else condition is never reached. Any help would be appreciated.

PopulateResult function:

```
def populateResult(df3):
 if(df3.AccountName2.isnull):
   return df3.AccountName
 elif(df3.AccountName.isnull):
   return df3.AccountName2
```

Function call:

```
 df3["ResultAccount"] = populateResult(df3)
```

Comment: It might just be about using it as df3.AccountName2.isnull() (You're missing the (). isnull is a function and needs to be called as one)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need double [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df3["ResultAccount"] = np.where(df3.AccountName2.isnull(), 
                                df3.AccountName, 
                                np.where(df3.AccountName.isnull(), 
                                         df3.AccountName2, 
                                         'None'))
print (df3)
```

Comment: It always gives the AccountName2. ResultAccount is always the AccountName2 value.

Comment: What return `df3.AccountName2.isnull()` ?